# Update challenge

Tags: android, android-listview

i made a list view containing all my calories of each ingredient and its name. im tying to update a Button text in the main class as the user alters the custom listview using buttons with their onclick method specified in the customlv class.

in my assignment question, users are able to change an ingredient in which it changes the corresponding calories. for example, eggs(500calories) to spinach(100calories). in which the 100 calories would be updated to the textview in the main class.

im having a error on line 79 for null pointer in which i would indicate

here are my codes:

Main class:

```
 public void recalculate(int sum) {
    Button recal;
     recal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.totalCalories);
    recal.setText("Total Calories : "+ sum);

 }
```

Mainclass :

```
    public IngredientCal(){}
```

customLv: ic1 is set here:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflate = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView1 = inflate.inflate(R.layout.list_single_two, null, true);

    final TextView ingredients1 = (TextView)rowView1.findViewById(R.id.ingredienttv);
    final TextView amt1 = (TextView)rowView1.findViewById(R.id.amounttv);
    final TextView cal1 = (TextView)rowView1.findViewById(R.id.caltv1);
    final Button alternate = (Button)rowView1.findViewById(R.id.alternate);
    final IngredientCal ic1 = new IngredientCal();
```

customlv: (in the Button on click method)
get view method

```
                @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflate = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView1 = inflate.inflate(R.layout.list_single_two, null, true);

    final TextView ingredients1 = (TextView)rowView1.findViewById(R.id.ingredienttv);
    final TextView amt1 = (TextView)rowView1.findViewById(R.id.amounttv);
    final TextView cal1 = (TextView)rowView1.findViewById(R.id.caltv1);
    final Button alternate = (Button)rowView1.findViewById(R.id.alternate);
    final IngredientCal ic1 = new IngredientCal();
    ingredients1.setText(""+ingredients.get(position));
    cal1.setText(""+cal.get(position));
    amt1.setText(""+amt.get(position));

    // alternate ingredient button
    if(alt.get(position) == 1){


        alternate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //
                if(x == 1){

                alternate.setText("Bck");

                String a = AltIngredients.get(position);
                String b = ""+calA.get(position);
                ingredients1.setText(""+a);
                cal1.setText(""+b);


                //add new ingredient,
                ingredients.remove(position);
                ingredients.add(position, AltIngredients.get(position));

                cal.remove(position);
                cal.add(position, calA.get(position));

                for(int i =0; i <cal.size(); i++){
                    sum += cal.get(i);

                    Log.i("SUM", ""+ cal.get(i) );
                }
                ic1.recalculate(sum);
                x--;

                }else{

                    alternate.setText("Alt");   

                    String a = ingredients.get(position);
                    String b = ""+cal.get(position);
                    ingredients1.setText(""+a);
                    cal1.setText(""+b);
                    x++;
                }
            }


        });




    }else{

        alternate.setEnabled(false);

    }



    return rowView1;





}
```

xml for main class:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/totalCalories"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total Calories : "
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/total"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
```

Comment: show where ic1 is set

Comment: oh yeah i forgot. well its there now. i also created a constructer for ingredientCal

Comment: Also show what IngredientCal is. We ain't magicians.

Comment: IngredientCal just sets the customeListview Adapter nth much thats all in the oncreate. i show the default constructor.

Comment: please read about variable scopes: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html. and you will understand why you are getting NPE.

Answer (score 0):

The NPE (Null Pointer Exception) is caused by the variable `ic1` being NULL.

From the content of your `getView` method, there is no way I can see the line `ic1.recalculate(sum);` would throw a NPE. As, `ic1` is clearly initialized before the `onClick` handler is registered. I am curious about the `sum` variable through, I would expect that to be declared inside the `onClick` method, but it is not declared anywhere.

Can you show us the declaration of `sum` ? And also update your question with the full null pointer exception trace you are receiving.

Comment: oh yes the on click is in the view because it referes to a button. the ic1 is decalred above that on click method

Comment: Could you please show the entire content of the `getView` method? There is something fishy. Somehow `ic1` is not being initialized before the on click method is called.

Comment: do advice me further. Been stuck for days hope u my savior